# GET request over 310 characters gets HTTP 400 Error

Tags: c#, get, webserver

I'm having an issue where calls to WebService fails with Error 400 - The request URL is invalid but only if the request length is more than 310 characters long.

Here's the server host setup:

```
            WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(DataService), new Uri(externalCommsEndpoint));

            WebHttpBinding restBinding = new WebHttpBinding
            {
                CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas() 
                { 
                    MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
                    MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647,
                    MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647
                }
            };

            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExternalComms), restBinding, externalCommsEndpoint);

            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });

            serviceHost.Open();
```

Here's the UriTemplate:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "createplan/{designid}/{accesstoken}/{contexttype=main}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Results CreateDesign(string designId, string accessToken, string contextType);
```

An example GET request that fails as it's 311 chars long:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7010/openit/createiton/NXL7-xTYU/eyJrgWQiOiJzaGRkZWZhdWx0IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2MTI0NTUwOTYsInN1YiI6ImxvZ2luIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDoxMjIwMS9jaXMvb2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2twc3dlYi1hcHAiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTIzNjg2OTYsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6Imtwcy1hZG1pbiIsInRlbmFuds
```

I've tried upping all the binding values (shown in example code) but this has had no effect, has anyone any idea why the 400 error occurs?

Comment: Does the response have newlines?

Comment: Nope, i should have investigated just a little longer though as I've found that by default no single URL segment can have more than 260 chars, it needs to be changed to a query string to work.

Answer (score 0):

After a little further investigation i found that the last URL segment had more than 260 chars. By default, no single segment can have more than 260 chars.

http://127.0.0.1:7010/notmorethan260/notmorethan260/notmorethan260